# AES Known-Plaintext-Attack and IV?

Tags: security, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

Edit: I address Known-Plaintext-Attack and Chosen-plaintext attack (both) with my question

I have a little problem understandig the right use of IV.

AES is only safe against Known-Plaintext-Attack if I use a different IV for every message. Right?

I need to know the used IV to decrypt a message. Also right?

AES that isn't protected against Known-Plaintext-Attack is a weak encryption. Right?

This means I have to store every IV with the encrypted data (e.g. in a extra DB column). Sounds like a lot of overhead.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This has nothing with programming. See at [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks) and look how CryptDB solved.

Comment: I am almost certain AES can be broken with Known-text attack the question is more on the line of which library of known text segments does the NSA possesses. The reason why I am certain about AES weakness is because there is at least one simpler, much simpler way to encrypt data instead of all the convoluted mess in AES. And from my experience, when you see a convoluted mess... "nice try Sisko. It's a fake."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 128 bit message, a 96 bit IV (for AES in GCM mode as per NIST recommendation) might look like a big overhead. But usually the plain text messages to be encrypted are much larger than that. Much larger as compared to the fixed size 96 bit IV.

On the other hand, almost every safe encryption or hashing mechanisms need a kind of randomness in the form of IV, nonce, salt etc. Not just AES.

It's an overhead but that is a tradeoff for security.

Usually IV is appended or prepended with the ciphertext. And decryption logic knows where to find it in the cipher text.

Overhead is everywhere. For e.g. in an RDBMS table when we create an index, it's an overhead in terms of space and write processing time. But it's a tradeoff for fast query performance.

Comment: The IV for AES is 128 bit

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen for AES GCM mode, NIST recommendation is 96 bit IV for efficiency and interoperability. But, I think I should update the answer mentioning that I meant GCM mode